# getting display name of field in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Is there a way to retrieve the display name of a field in MS CRM? So far I can only get the schema name; but I want to be able to display something a bit more user friendly. Example below would return `hc_billtimeunit3` but want to return `bill time unit` instead.

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_billtimeunit3").getName()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below snippet to get the label text.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("attibutename").getLabel();
```

or

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("attibutename").getLabel();
```

Both are working seemless for me, as `Xrm.Page.getControl` method is a shortcut method to access `Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get`

To get display name from CRM entity customizations, you may need another service call.

Comment: that just returned [object] to me but Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("attibutename").getLabel(); worked!

Comment: Xrm.Page.getControl("attibutename") will return [object].  Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("attibutename") will return [object].

Answer (score 1):

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("attibutename").getLabel();
```

this actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is for v9.x version

```
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
formContext.getControl("attibutename").getLabel();
```